# Licensing system without Internet connection

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-lvl

I'm testing the licensing system for android. Exactly I just compiled the sample project with ServerManagedPolicy and I have a question about it:
If I do:

```
Device's Internet=ON
Launch the app
Launch the check= Allow access
Device's Internet=OFF
Relaunch app and check= Allow access
```

Ok now lets see the problem:

```
Device's Internet=OFF
Launch the app
Launch the check= Don't allow access
```

Logically I don't want that. Because the app will be blocked if the user launches the app without Internet, even if it was licensed. How can I solve that? My application needs to be connected to the Internet for working so there's no problem in delaying that check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a custom LicenseValidator class with  a handleResponse() that would call dontAllow() on the License checker callback only when the policy returns LicenseResponse.NOT_LICENSED, and allow() in all other cases including network error.

```
 public class LicenseValidator {
...
    public void handleResponse(LicenseResponse response, ResponseData rawData) {
        mPolicy.processServerResponse(response);
        if (mPolicy.allowAccess()) {
            mCallback.allow();
        } else if (response == LicenseResponse.NOT_LICENSED) {
            mCallback.dontAllow();
        }
    }
```

And use also a custom Policy instead of the ServerManagedPolicy:

```
public class MyPolicy {
private LicenseResponse mLastResponse;

public MyPolicy(Activity activity) {
    mLastResponse = LicenseResponse.RETRY;
}

public void processServerResponse(LicenseResponse response) {
    mLastResponse = response;
}

public boolean allowAccess() { 
    return (LicenseResponse.LICENSED.equals(mLastResponse));
}
```

}

This is petty much what I did and it works fine.